# How to handle background updates and form input in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to figure out how to set up the contexts to handle background updates and also be able to handle form input.  Here's what I did but I know it's wrong because I have the issue where the form gets rerendered and the data disappears

```
<BackendDataContextProvider>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="list" component="ListDataFromBackendComponent">
    <Stack.Screen name="update" component="UpdateEntryComponent">
  </Stack.Navigator>
</BackendDataContextProvider>
```

The `BackendDataContextProvider` has a state called `dataFromBackend` which is set every 60 seconds.

`UpdateEntryComponent` does not rely on the `dataFromBackend` info but because of the heirarchy it is still rerenders.

I am thinking I have to change `BackendDataContextProvider` to split it into a background fetcher and another component that is used in the `ListDataFromBackendComponent`

However, is there a less "drastic" approach that I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) (class Components) or [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) (functional components).
They are used to prevent child rerenders which are solely caused because the parent is rerendering.

Comment: I actually did but I may have been doing it wrong since it's still rerendering the component.